# transfer 1000 files at a time from one s3 bucket to another using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy files from one s3 bucket to another. But the thing is I just want to transfer 1000 files at a time and in total I have 300,000 files. And another thing is I want to give 15 sec time between batches to transfer.

I have written below code, which copy from one s3 to another but server is getting stuck. So please help me with this problem.

```
aws s3 cp s3://sources3bucket/ s3://dests3bucket --recursive
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you only want to copy 1000 at a time? Is this simply your attempt at a workaround for issues you are seeing? Also, have you tried aws s3 sync? And are the buckets in the same region?

Comment: @jarmod Actually, I want to load file to RDS db, and I have written a lambda function for that, if csv file is loaded in the destination bucket then lambda function is called. It loads into RDS.  I have 350k csv's stored in s3 bucket which I need to move to other s3 bucket( but lambda function can handle only 1000 files (max) at a time). That's why I am looking to transfer 1000 files at a time from source s3 to dest s3.

Comment: @jarmod, yes buckets are in the same region.

Comment: If you exceed 1000 simultaneous Lambda executions, the extras will queue-up, so you do not necessarily need to stop at 1000.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I thought the same that it should queue up but it's not working that way. It's getting stuck when so many files are loaded at once. So, that's why I want to write script where it will take 1000 files in a batch and load it to s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Step Functions to copy files from one Bucket to Another. The steps involves

- Write the Lambda Functions to Copy files from Source based on the given Source Bucket Parameter and to Save it to a Destination Bucket.
- Setup a Step Function Workflow
- You can also add a delay of 15 seconds configured in the Workflow.

For more details refer the Blog Article in AWS Compute Blob [Synchronizing Amazon S3 Buckets Using AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/synchronizing-amazon-s3-buckets-using-aws-step-functions/).

Sample code is available in [SyncBucketsStateMachine](https://github.com/awslabs/sync-buckets-state-machine) Github Repository.

Comment: I have written a script to transfer files between s3 buckets. Could you please help in setting up setup Function workflow?

Comment: Hi. Whats the issue you are facing?